# delete previous messages if includes a word using discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

IM trying to filter my discord server and i want to get rid of all messages containing swear words (including previous messages) . Any idea on how i could do this? i can delete messages sent when my bot is online but i am looking for a way to delete messages months old. This is my code so far.

```
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
   
    message.content.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();

    const bannedWords = ["0", "1", "2", "3"];

    for (var i = 0; i < bannedWords.length; i++) {
        if (message.content.includes(bannedWords[i])){  
            message.delete();
            break
        }
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the messages and then filter to delete

```js
const bannedWords = [""] //Array of banned words
let messages = await message.channel.messages.fetch() //Fetch the messages from the channel

let filtered = messages.filter(m=> m.content.includes(bannedWords)) //Filtering the messages
message.channel.bulkDelete(filtered)
```